# DRF Search on ArrayField

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

**Specifications:**
django==1.11.5
djangorestframework==3.6.4
PostgreSQL 9.6.5 on x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0, compiled by Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.1.76), 64-bit
Python 3.6.2

`models.py`

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField
from django.db import models
from djchoices import DjangoChoices, ChoiceItem


class Customer(models.Model):
    ...
    phones = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=30))
```

`filters.py`

```
import django_filters
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend
from rest_framework.filters import FilterSet
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet

from soken_web.apps.customers.api.serializers import CustomerSerializer
from soken_web.apps.customers.models import Customer


class CharInFilter(django_filters.BaseInFilter, django_filters.CharFilter):
    pass


class CustomerFilter(FilterSet):
    phones = CharInFilter(name='phones', lookup_expr='contains')

    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = (
            ...,
            'phones',
        )


class CustomerViewset(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Customer.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CustomerSerializer
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_class = CustomerFilter
    filter_fields = (
        ...
        'phones',
    )
```

**References:**
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-filter/ns7zx1C8HN8

**AS IS:**
I have to search the exact match phone number of that customer.
For example `customer.phones = ['024382426', '024387269']`
I have to filter with `024382426` to get that `customers`.

**Question:**
How to do put the phone number in short like `438` and get that `customer`?

Answer (score 2):

ArrayField is actually a **list**. And for list lookup, **in** keyword is used. You are using **contains**, and that is for CharField.
You need to put **in** as the **lookup_expr** like this :

```
import django_filters
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend
from rest_framework.filters import FilterSet
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet

from soken_web.apps.customers.api.serializers import CustomerSerializer
from soken_web.apps.customers.models import Customer


class NumberInFilter(django_filters.BaseInFilter, django_filters.NumberFilter):
    pass


class CustomerFilter(FilterSet):
    phones = NumberInFilter(name='phones', lookup_expr='in')

    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = (
            ...,
            'phones',
        )


class CustomerViewset(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Customer.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CustomerSerializer
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_class = CustomerFilter
    filter_fields = (
        ...
        'phones',
    )
```

And for Arrayfield, you need **NumberFilter** in the place of **CharFilter**. Updated this also, Please check.

Comment: ```operator does not exist: character varying[] = text[]
LINE 1: ...ers_customer" WHERE "customers_customer"."phones" IN (ARRAY[...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.```

Comment: @Sarit This is a PostgreSQL error, you are comparing integers with varchar or string. Please make both search field and key field consistent with each other.

Comment: Let me try put quote or double-quote to it. One moment.

Comment: Quote is turned to be %27 &phones=%27438%27, and double-quote is %22 And raises same problem ```operator does not exist: character varying[] = text[]
LINE 1: ...house"."id") WHERE ("customers_customer"."phones" IN (ARRAY[...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.```

Comment: @Sarit Refer this. http://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/develop/ref/filters.html#baseinfilter

Comment: @Sarit you are using a combination of django_filters.CharFilter and NumberFilter which is raising this error. Please resolve on the basis of above link.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154648/discussion-between-prakhar-trivedi-and-sarit).

Comment: @Sarit Updated my answer. Please check.

Comment: 'decimal.Decimal' object is not iterable